How to change the base url path in coldfusion
I have two diffrent sites one is old and one is new.
So whenever I tried logging to old website URL it automatically should redirect new site URL.
Example
My Old url is :https://X2.bird.com
New is :httpd://x2.insight.com
When I tried to login to old one it should automatically redirected to new one
Is there any way that we can do in coldfusion

This should be handled at the web server, not the application server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/
